# How to increase excerpt length in wordpress?

Tags: php

Thank you for your help!

functions.php

```
function excerpt($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
array_pop($excerpt);
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
} else {
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
}
$excerpt = preg_replace('`[[^]]*]`','',$excerpt);
return $excerpt;
}
```

index.php

```
<div class="post excerpt <?php echo (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'last' : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: Please decide yourself of which of [those other questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=excerpt+length) yours is a duplicate of. About your `php` tag: Nearly every question about WordPress is a PHP question, so please don't use that tag - find a better one (or multiple). Question: What does the `index.php` line about the classes has to do with the excerpt length? And last, please tell us what your actual problem is. "Thank you for your help!" does add no information to the question, still it is the only full sentence in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
  return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Add above code to your `functions.php`, and set the value 999 to the desired length.

Source: [**`the_excerpt()`** — Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)

Comment: 999 isn't the 'desired length' of the excerpt required, that's the priority of the filter. It's the '20' bit you want to change.

Comment: @BIOSTALL You are aware you're replying on a comment made in 2013, right? Things probably have changed in the last 5 years.

Comment: The comment by @BIOSTALL is still correct.